# Javascript: Encapsulation & Abstraction

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

I am writing an application code in javascript.

I just want an expect advice on how Encapsulation be achieved in JS,

The pattern which I wrote is something like,

```
var app = (function (window) {

    // define variables here

    // define functions here       


    return {
        init: function () {},
        plotGraph: function () {},
        plotTable: function () {},
        resizeHanlder: function () {},
        initMenu: function () {},
        attachEvent: function () {}
    }



})(this);
```

Is there anything better than this.

### Why I am doing this?

I really do not want to pollute global scope

Comment: Why close vote...I have asked for best pattern..Also I provided code which I tried

Comment: Isn't this more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Yoshi how can I move this to code review?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to make is called **revealing module pattern**. Here is one link on this topic:

https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/

Let's short analyse your code:

- There will be only one global variable `app`. It get assigned the result of an anonymous functions, which is self-executed (we'll see that in the last line), also called Immediately-Invoked Function Expressin (IIFE).

  ```
  var app = (function (window) {
  ```
- The function returns an object which is assigned to the variable `app`

  ```
  return {
      init: init,
      plotGraph: function () {},
      plotTable: function () {},
      resizeHanlder: function () {},
      initMenu: function () {},
      attachEvent: function () {}
  }
  ```
- The following code will never be executed, as the function already returned a value in the previous step.

  ```
  function init() {}
  ```
- And this here makes the function self-executable.

  ```
  })(this);
  ```

Since your code has errors I would give you a simple example how to implement the revealing module pattern:

```
var hello = (function () {
    var sayHello, makeGreeting;

    sayHello = function () {
        return 'Hello, ';
    };

    makeGreeting = function (name) {
        console.log(sayHello() + name);
    }

    return {
        makeGreeting : makeGreeting
    };
})();
```

Now we have one object `hello` with one method `makeGreeting`. There is additional logic within which is not exposed to the end user, because he/she doesn't need to know it or isn't supposed to change those values.

Here is another example for this pattern from my GitHub:

https://github.com/cezar77/roman/blob/master/roman.js

Comment: cezar...I did not post complete code..this is incompete...just looking for suggestion on patterns..do not look for errors

Comment: @Pilot My suggestion was also regarding the best practice to implement the pattern. First define all variables, then implement your logic and in the end return an object with the public methods.